# Cannot upload large file to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

It is okay when dealing with small files. It doesn't work only when I try to upload large files. I'm using Python client. The snippet is:

```
filename='my_csv.csv'
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = os.environ["GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET"]
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob("{}".format(filename))
blob.upload_from_filename(filename)  # file size is 500 MB
```

The only thing I get as a Traceback is "Killed" and I'm out of python interpreter.

Any suggestions are highly appriciated

**Edit:**
It works okay from local machine. My application runs in Google Container Engine, so problems occurs there when runs in celery task.

Comment: Try to monitor your app's memory usage while it is running, it may be using too much and trigger the [OOM killer](https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer). You *might* find something about it in the system log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uploading the file in chunks. You can find samples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/97485/apiclient.http.MediaFileUpload). (search for `request.next_chunk()`)

Comment: Documentation: https://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest-class.html

Answer (score 5):

`upload_by_filename` attempts to upload the entire file in a single request.

You can use `Blob.chunk_size` to spread the upload across many requests, each responsible for uploading one "chunk" of your file.

For example:

`my_blob.chunk_size = 1024 * 1024 * 10`

Answer (score 3):

I kind of find the examples in the accepted answer a bit difficult to follow. (No doubt that it is very professionally written.)

The following made it much easier for me. Sharing in case it helps others as well..

```
from google.cloud import storage


def upload_file_to_gcp_bucket(service_account_json, 
                              bucket_name, 
                              file_to_upload, 
                              file_name_in_gcp):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 262144 # This needs to be a multiple of 262144


storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(service_account_json)

# create a bucket object
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(file_name_in_gcp, chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE)
blob.upload_from_filename(file_to_upload)
```